# Is it possible to get nd4j working on linux-arm system?

Tags: java, maven, artificial-intelligence, raspbian, deeplearning4j

I'm trying to get a maven project built with an nd4j dependency on a linux ARM system.
Here's my current dependency in my pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
     <version>0.9.1</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Here is the error I'm getting when trying to do a maven install on my ARM system

> Could not resolve dependencies for project com.test.test:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.nd4j:nd4j-native:jar:linux-arm:0.9.1, org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:openblas:jar:linux-arm:0.2.19-1.3: Failure to find org.nd4j:nd4j-native:jar:linux-arm:0.9.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced